# How can I Retrieve a List of All Table Names from a SQL Server CE database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, database-schema

Is there some SQL that will either return a list of table names or (to cut to the chase) that would return a boolean as to whether a tablename with a certain pattern exists?

Specifically, I need to know if there is a table in the database named `INV[Bla]` such as `INVclay`, `INVcherri`, `INVkelvin`, `INVmorgan`, `INVgrandFunk`, `INVgobbledygook`, `INV2468WhoDoWeAppreciate`, etc. (the `INV` part is what I'm looking for; the remainder of the table name could be almost anything).

IOW, can "wildcards" be used in a SQL statement, such as:

```
SELECT * tables 
FROM database 
WHERE tableName = 'INV*'
```

or how would this be accomplished?

Comment: Although it may not apply in your situation, it's a good idea to include the table schema--not just in your query above, but when you implement one of the answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you there:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 where table_name LIKE '%INV%'
```

EDIT:
fixed `table_name`

Answer (score 1):

To check for exists:

--

### -- note that the sql compiler knows that it just needs to check for existence, so this is a case where "select *" is just fine

if exists
   (select *
    from   [sys].[tables]
    where  upper([name]) like N'INV%')
  select N'do something appropriate because there is a table based on this pattern';

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.tables where name LIKE 'INV%';
```