# Not able to find table when querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, database-schema

Based on intelligence gleaned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391415/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-all-table-names-from-a-sql-server-ce-database), I tried this query against my SQL CE table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'INV%' OR TABLE_NAME LIKE 'DSD%'
```

...but it returned nothing; however, as you can see:

[image]

...INVvalerie should be returned; shouldn't it?

Comment: What happens if the WHERE clause is eliminated? What table names are returned, if any?

Comment: you sure that the table name doesn't include a schema or someother text in front of it. i.e. table_name isn't really something like `dbo.INVValerie`, so your like won't match (i.e. starts with `'INV'` hence the `'INV%'`, try `like '%INV%'` as per your referenced article. To check what is being reutrned just list out the table names and see what you are getting from the query first (i.e. something like `SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` no where

Comment: Now it's working (the SQL shown above, no changes); I guess I had to warm boot the device. The whole shebang is qwirkier than a Quark and touchier than Tiny Tim.

Comment: Does this deprecated CE thing that you shouldn't be using anymore support catalog views like `sys.tables` [instead of the awful and incomplete `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx)?

Comment: @Aaron No, it does not... and the missing items do not apply to SQL Server Compact